# How to pass 2D array as a Range for Google Spreadsheet Chart?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say we have:

Column A:

```
Cat
Dog
Pig
```

Column B:

```
2
3
4
```

Add a new chart function:

```
function newChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();

  var data = ss.getSheets()[0];

  Logger.log(activeRange.getValues())

  var chart = data.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
     .addRange(activeRange)
     .setPosition(3, 2, 0, 0)
     .setOption('title','Farm')
     .build();

  data.insertChart(chart);
}
```

activeRange in cells A1:B3;
activeRange values (2D array):

> ```
> [15-07-30 15:59:02:865 EDT] [[Cat, 2.0], [Dog, 3.0], [Pig, 4.0]]
> ```

But when I tried to pass 2D array as a range

```
  var range = [['Cat', 2.0], ['Dog', 3.0], ['Pig', 4.0]];

  var chart = data.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
     .addRange(range)
     .setPosition(3, 2, 0, 0)
     .setOption('title','Farm')
     .build();
```

I got next error:

> Cannot convert Array to Range.

Please, help me to figure out how to pass 2D array as a range.

Comment: it expects a sheet range and not an array. see other chart methods theres likely another one for pasing the raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting the array object to range by setting the values in to a range. Check this code below:

```
function newChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = [['Cat', 2.0], ['Dog', 3.0], ['Pig', 4.0]];
  var activeRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 3, 2).setValues(range);
  var data = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var chart = data.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
     .addRange(activeRange)
     .setPosition(3, 2, 0, 0)
     .setOption('title','Farm')
     .build();

  data.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Tried and able to get the pie chart for the array values. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this can be useful for somebody. Simple function to create a chart from active range:

```
  // global
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();

function newChart() {

  // Get values from Active Range:
  var source = activeRange.getValues();

  // Get only unique entries (uses 2D Arrays Library):
  var uniqueCount = ArrayLib.unique(source)

  // Some rearrangemen to get propper output:
  var sourceOutput = [];  
     for(var i = 0; i < uniqueCount.length; i++)
{
    sourceOutput = sourceOutput.concat(uniqueCount[i]);
}

  // Empty arr
  var empArr = new Array([]);

  var counts = {};    
     for(var i = 0; i< source.length; i++) {
        var num = source[i];   
       if(empArr < num){
    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num]+1 : 1;
       }    
}

  var keyArray = Object.keys(counts).map(function (key) {return counts[key]});

  var output=[];
     for(i=0;i<sourceOutput.length;i++){
       output.push( [sourceOutput[i], keyArray[i] ]);
};

  Logger.log(output)

  // Create a chart
  var data = ss.getSheets()[0];  
  var outputRange=data.getRange(10, 1, uniqueCount.length, 2).setValues(output);  
  var chart = data.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
     .addRange(outputRange)
     .setPosition(3, 3, 0, 0)
     .setOption('title','%your_title%')
     .build();

  data.insertChart(chart);
}
```